# Bash: the first path then the second as relative path to the first path in the same command

Tags: bash, zsh, fish

Let's say I want: `ln -s /very/long/path/to_file /very/long/path/from_file`

Is there a way not to type full path to the from_file again?

smth like: `ln -s /very/long/path/to_file [sign]/from_file`

where `sign` is automatically revealed as `/very/long/path`

May be you know some ways for bash, zsh or fish?

Comment: While @faho answered your specific question I'd like to point out that your symlink is needlessly inefficient. Traversing it will cause the kernel to traverse `/very/long/path` twice. You should be using a relative symlink: `ln -s to_file /very/long/path/from_file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brace expansion!

```
ln -s /very/long/path/{to_file,from_file}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can store in a variable like this:

```
variable=/very/long/path
```

Then use it like this:

```
ln -s $variable/to_file $variable/from_file
```

Comment: Of course I don't meant any previously prepared variable. I'm looking for 'sign' that automatically reveals as current relative path for the second argument defined in the first argument/path.

Comment: If you need to reuse that `/very/long/path` it needs to be stored somewhere.

Comment: If you need to reuse that `/very/long/path` it needs to be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if using Bash, cut (the previous word, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd>) and paste (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>) is your friend:

`$ ln -s /very/long/path/` <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>`to_file` <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>`from_file`

If there is space in the path, you need to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> more.

Comment: Are there better ways in zsh or fish shell?

Comment: No idea, I don't use them.